# Keychain error -34018, unable to delete current dictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain, ios10, xcode8

I have an app that is written in Swift 2.3. The app uses the KeychainItemWrapper that makes accessing the Keychain simpler.

When I run the app in the iOS 9.3 simulator with Xcode, the app runs as expected and there are no issues reading/writing to the keychain.

The same exact app, without any changes in my code, crashes with the call to:

```
- (void)resetKeychainItem
```

With the line:

```
SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)tempDictionary);
```

Thus making this NSAssert give me my error:

```
NSAssert( junk == noErr || junk == errSecItemNotFound, @"Problem deleting current dictionary." );
```

Researching this error by the code 34018 pointed me to other posts with users experiencing a bug with the keychain that was actually brought to the attention of the devs at Apple. It was made a high priority bug, and one post suggested iOS 9.3 had a fix for this (my app works on iOS 9.3!).

However, it is my understanding that Xcode 8 handles such things as code signing differently than previous versions. So I wonder if with iOS 10 if this is a possible new bug.

If anyone has any ideas or experience with this error on iOS 10/Xcode 8... please share your suggestions.